# How to stop subprocesses that communicate with the main process through request and response queues?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe, client-server, message-queue

I have a Python program that starts *N* subprocesses (clients) which send requests to and listen for responses from the main process (server). The interprocess communication uses pipes through `multiprocessing.Queue` objects according to the following scheme (one queue per consumer, so one request queue and *N* response queues):

```
                1 req_queue
                              <-- Process-1
MainProcess <-- ============= <-- …
                              <-- Process-N

                N resp_queues
            --> ============= --> Process-1
MainProcess --> ============= --> …
            --> ============= --> Process-N
```

The (simplified) program:

```py
import multiprocessing


def work(event, req_queue, resp_queue):
    while not event.is_set():
        name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
        x = 3
        req_queue.put((name, x))
        print(name, 'input:', x)
        y = resp_queue.get()
        print(name, 'output:', y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    event = multiprocessing.Event()
    req_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    resp_queues = {}
    processes = {}
    N = 10
    for _ in range(N):  # start N subprocesses
        resp_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        process = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=work, args=(event, req_queue, resp_queue))
        resp_queues[process.name] = resp_queue
        processes[process.name] = process
        process.start()
    for _ in range(100):  # handle 100 requests
        (name, x) = req_queue.get()
        y = x ** 2
        resp_queues[name].put(y)
    event.set()  # stop the subprocesses
    for process in processes.values():
        process.join()
```

The problem that I am facing is that the execution of this program (under Python 3.11.2) sometimes never stops, hanging at the line `y = resp_queue.get()` in some subprocess once the main process notify subprocesses to stop at the line `event.set()`. The problem is the same if I use the `threading` library instead of the `multiprocessing` library.

How to stop the subprocesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`queue.get()` is a blocking function, a thread (process) reaching it will wait until an item is put on the queue, it won't be woken up by setting the event if it has already reached the `get()` line.

The way that's usually done (even in the standard modules) is to send a `None`  (or another meaningless object) on the queue to wake the processes waiting on the queue and have them terminate when there is no more work.

```py
event.set()
for queue_obj in resp_queues:
    queue_obj.put(None)
```

This makes your event only useful for early termination, but if early termination is not needed you can just omit the event from the workers altogether.

```py
def work(event, req_queue, resp_queue):
    while True:
        ...
        y = resp_queue.get()
        print(name, 'output:', y)
        if y is None:
            break
```

Obviously just using `queue.get()` can lead to resources leak if the main process fails, so another solution that you should do is to use a timeout on the queue and not leave it waiting forever.

```py
y = resp_queue.get(timeout=0.1)
```

This makes sure the processes will terminate eventually on "unexpected failures", but sending the `None` is what's used for instantaneous termination.

If you have multiple `resp_queue.get()` embedded throughout your code that a simple `break on None` won't work then you can use `sys.exit()` when you receive the `None` to terminate the worker, this will do the necessary cleanup and can only be caught be a bare `except:`, the code that intercepts the `None` and calls `sys.exit` can be hidden in a subclass of `multiprocessing.queues.Queue`.

```py
class MyQueue(multiprocessing.queues.Queue):

    def get(self, block: bool=False, timeout: Optional[float]=None) -> object:
        # set a default alternative timeout if you want
        return_value = super().get(block=block, timeout=timeout)  
        if return_value is None:  # or another dummy class as a signal
            sys.exit()  # or raise a known exception
        return return_value
```

Comment: Thank you! What I forgot to mention is that in my code I don’t control the worker code because it can be redefined by the user in a subclass, and typically the user will use multiple request–response pairs in the `work` function. So sending a single `None` sentinel per worker to unblock the `y = resp_queue.get()` call may not be enough as their can be several of such calls. Do you have a solution for an open-ended number of `y = resp_queue.get()` calls?

Comment: @Maggyero you can simply call `sys.exit` when you get the `None` signal, which does the necessary resources cleanup but can only be caught by a bare `except:`, and to hide it from the user you can hide it inside a subclass of `multiprocessing.queue` that you will be using.

Comment: Very interesting, could you add this to your answer? And +1 for the subtle distinction between early termination and late termination in your answer.

Comment: I found an alternative solution to yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75644825/2326961), what are your thoughts on this? I’ll accept your answer anyway.

Comment: @Maggyero seems like a hacky way to make sure each `get` is matched by a `None`, but what if the number of requests is varying each run by a condition or a loop ? you could still run into the deadlock.

Comment: Do you mean what if the number of requests `req_queue.put((name, x))` does not match the number of responses `y = resp_queue.get()` in the `work` function?

Comment: @Maggyero exactly

Comment: Yes that would dead lock. A matching number of requests and responses in the `work` function is indeed an assumption of my alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution to [@AhmedAEK’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75644292/2326961) which works for an open-ended number of request–response pairs in the `work` function, i.e. an open-ended number of `req_queue.put((name, x))` and `y = resp_queue.get()` call pairs (in my real program I don’t control the worker code because it can be redefined by the user in a subclass):

```py
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    event.set()
    try:
        while True:
            (name, x) = req_queue.get(timeout=1)
            resp_queues[name].put(None)
    except queue.Empty:
        pass
    ...
```